# Have a Controller for Each Cell of a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView with 4 Cells, I have a controller for those 4 pages called SwipingController.

I'd like to have a UIViewController for each cell, how can I achieve that ?

Comment: What do you need a  dedicated controller per cell for? You could simply declare a property on the cell and have the cell instantiate the controller, however the end result might not be what you need.

Comment: @Cristik Each cell contains a UITableView. My idea is to have a dedicated Controller for each cell, this way, the controller will handle the content of the UITableView. Here is what I did for now: https://github.com/mathieubrmd/Heisenhower-Matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I counter advise on what you are going for.

Better just to have **Views** that manage their layout you don't need controllers to manage layout.
I don't think you will be able to hold a familiar architecture (MVC/MVVM/MVP/VIPER .. ) in the future if you go in this direction.

Also check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/index.html) out. It will help you understand better the role of a view controller.

Nonetheless you can achieve this with `addChildViewController`([documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621394-addchildviewcontroller))

Add child view

```
let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "test") as! UIViewController
self.addChildViewController(controller)
controller.view.frame = CGRect(0, 44, 320, 320)
self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Remove child view

```
let vc = self.childViewControllers.last
vc.removeFromSuperview()
vc.willMove(toParentViewController: nil);
vc.removeFromParentViewController()
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. From what I understand, the controller will make the communication between my view and my model. In my case, I need to communicate Task (my model) to my view through a VC. How should I populate my TableView If I don't have a controller ?

Comment: the table view has the property of delegate and datasource which you can set to be the same controller that handles the collection view

Comment: Thanks for your time. I think I'll use childVCs ;)